# Grails domain class validator, property must be greater than another property

Tags: validation, grails

I have the following domain class in my grails project:

```
class Vacation {
  Date start
  Date end

  User vacationer

  static constraints = {
    start(validator: {return (it >= new Date()-1)})
  }
}
```

Is it possible to add a validator that requires end to be equal or greater than start?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
start(validator: { 
   val, obj ->
      val < obj.properties['end']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access property "end", since obj is the object of the class Vacation only, where it is defined. 
Use:

start(validator: { 
   val, obj ->
      val < obj.end
})